# How to unsubscribe from unexisting IMAP folder in mutt?

Tags: mutt

How does one unsubsribe from a no longer existing IMAP folder in mutt?

**context**:

trying the relatively new sidebar feature, showing all subscribed folders, there's a bunch that show up that don't exist anymore (possibly deleted using a webmail interface at some point)

**tried**:

- reading in-app help, searching here and elsewhere on the web, I can only find the 'u' shortcut to unsubscribe from the within the list of folders that shows up when c-hanging to a different folder, but obviously no-longer existing folders do not appear on that list...
- tried to find which cache file or similar contains the information about subscribed folders, in order to remove manually, but couldn't find where this information is stored...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, digging deeper I eventually found how to do it:

1. from mutt index, type 'c' to access folder chooser
2. typing 'T' there toggles the view between actually existing folders and subscribed folders - in the second case, subscribed folders that don't really exist do show!
3. select the incriminated folder and type 'u' to unsubscribe

So, problem solved, but I'm still intrigued as to **where** the folder subscription information is stored (I was assuming on a dotfile, but no amount of `grep`ing showed me one under `.mutt` or `.cache/mutt*` that does).

Comment: IMAP folder subscriptions are stored by the server and you can use any IMAP client to modify the list of subscribed folders. See https://superuser.com/q/61585/247588  Unfortunately, many mail programs (including Mutt) don't also remove the folder subscription if a folder is removed or renamed.

Answer (score 1):

IMAP folder subscription can be local or serverside. AFAIK, usually, MUAs implement serverside subscription, sometimes they do both. My best guess is, **mutt does serverside subscription**. The [mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#imap-check-subscribed) hints at this only so much. Authoritative answer lies in the source. Or investigate your IMAP server's data.

HTH